# What is the probability that the mouse ever gets to eat the cheese?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm doing an exercise about Markov chain.

> A merry mouse moves in a maze. If it is at time $n$ in a room with $k$ horizontal or vertical adjacent rooms, it will be at time $n+1$ in one of the $k$ adjacent rooms, choosing one at random, each with probability $1 / k$. A fat lazy cat remains all the time in room $3,$ and a piece of cheese waits for the mouse in room $5$ The mouse starts in room $1$. See the following figure:
>
> [image]
>
> The cat is not completely lazy: If the mouse enters the room inhabited by the cat, the cat will eat it. Also, if the mouse eats the cheese, it rests forever. Let $X_{n}$ be the position of the mouse at time $n$.
>
> What is the probability that the mouse ever gets to eat the cheese?

From the graph, the transition matrix is as follows:

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then the probability that the mouse ever gets to eat the cheese is $$\mathbb P \left (\forall n \in \mathbb N:X_n \neq 5 \right )$$

Could you please leave me some hints to compute this probability? Thank you so much!

Comment: I think your transition matrix is wrong. Both $3$ and $5$ should be absorbing states,  and also the probability that the mouse ever gets to eat the cheese is
$$
\mathbb P(\inf\{n>0:X_n=5\}<\infty).
$$

Comment: Hi @Math1000, I think it's also correct to write $\mathbb P(\inf\{n\ge0:X_n=5\}<\infty)$, right?

Comment: True, that does take into account the case where $X_0=5$. But presumably we aren't very interested in that case, since then the probability is trivially one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transition matrix should actually be
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0\\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 &1/3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $X_n$ be the state the mouse is in at time $n$, then $\{X_n:n=0,1,2,\ldots\}$ is a Markov chain on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ with the above transition probabilities. We want to compute $\mathbb P(\tau_1)$, where
$$
\tau_i = \inf\{n>0: X_n = 5 \mid X_0 = i\},\quad i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}.
$$
It is clear that $\mathbb P(\tau_3)=0$ and $\mathbb P(\tau_5)=1$. To compute the remaining $\tau_i$ we have the system of linear equations
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\tau_1) &= P_{12}\mathbb P(\tau_2) + P_{14}\mathbb P(\tau_4)\\
\mathbb P(\tau_2) &= P_{21}\mathbb P(\tau_1)\\
\mathbb P(\tau_4) &= P_{41}\mathbb P(\tau_1) + P_{45}.
\end{align}
Substituting in the transition probabilities, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\tau_1) &= 1/2\mathbb P(\tau_2) + 1/2\mathbb P(\tau_4)\\
\mathbb P(\tau_2) &= 1/2\mathbb P(\tau_1)\\
\mathbb P(\tau_4) &= 1/3\mathbb P(\tau_1) + 1/3.
\end{align}
This yields
$$
\mathbb P(\tau_1) = \frac27,\quad \mathbb P(\tau_2) = \frac17,\quad \mathbb P(\tau_4) = \frac37.
$$
Indeed, if we compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}P^n$ (which exists since $P$ is aperiodic), we get
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{7} & 0 & \frac{2}{7} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{6}{7} & 0 & \frac{1}{7} \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{7} & 0 & \frac{3}{7} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),
$$
and the desired $\mathbb P(\tau_i)$ values can be read off the last column of this matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the probability that the mouse survives to get the cheese starting in room 1 equals the one half the probability he survives if he finds himself in room 2 + the probability he survives if he finds himself in room 4

$P_1 = \frac 12 P_2 + \frac 12P_4\\
P_2 = \frac 12 P_1\\
P_4 = \frac 13 P_1 + \frac 13$

We have a system of 3 linear equations with 3 unknowns.

This should be simple enough to solve.

I get $P_1 = \frac {2}{7}$